# rich:dataTable not rendering in h:form

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am in the process of migrating Richfaces 3.x to 4.x, using JSF 2.0
Here I have used rich:dataTable component inside h:form, but it is not getting dispalyed.
in browser view source it is not convering in to html format, its still showing rich:dataTable.

and we don't place any new rich.tld files in WEB-INF folder,
but previous 3.x version i had this rich.tld, richfaces.tld files in my WEB-INF folder.

can some one help me out on this, what could be the problem here to render the datatable ?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-Upgrading

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `rich.tld` and `a4j.tld` in RichFaces 4.x.

JSP pages are not supported in RichFaces 4 (they are deprecated in JSF 2). It is reason why  these files are not applicable in RichFaces 4.

Comment: Thank you, and one more thing, what about the html_basic.tld file, should I remove this file also from WEB-INF ? if i delete this .tld file my jsf components like h:form, h:outPutText are not recognizing, those are showing red in xhtml pages.

Comment: You don't need any .tld file. You need create template(s) and rewrite page(s) using it.